# Logistic Regression : Solving the cross-entropy cost function analytically

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cost-function

Logistic regression cost function is cross-entropy. It is defined as below:

[image: J(θ)=1m∑i=1m−(y(i)×log(hθ(x(i)))+(1−y(i))×log(1−hθ(x(i))))]

This is a convex function. To reach the minimum, scikit-learn provides multiple types of solvers such  as : ‘liblinear’ library, ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’ and ‘lbfgs’.

Is it possible to analytically find the minimum? if yes, what can we say of the computing complexity?

Comment: Have you checked this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/949/when-is-logistic-regression-solved-in-closed-form)? It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use just one neuron (linear->sigmoid), you can find the minimum with too much small error or maybe reach to the minimum using approaches like gradient descent or other optimization algorithms. The reason for finding the minimum is that cross entropy is a non-convex shape, but if you use sigmoid function as the activation function of logistic regression, the cross entropy cost function becomes convex and it is easy to find the only global minimum.

Comment: I am searching for an analytical solution expression with a closed form. Looking at Shadi answer, it seems that the solution can't be easily expressed for most of logistic regression problems (more than two input variables...).